# wp_update_post making my post sticky

Tags: wp-update-post

I am updating my post using below code:

```
$post_information = array(
    'ID' => $_REQUEST['ID'],
    'post_content' =>  $_REQUEST['content'],
    'post_status'  =>  'publish'
);
wp_update_post($post_information);
```

But when I update my post, then it also make my post sticky,
Please tell me how update my post whiteout making it sticky.

Answer (score 1):

I need to add: `post_date_gmt`

```
$post_information = array(
    'ID' => $_REQUEST['ID'],
    'post_content' =>  $_REQUEST['content'],
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'post_date_gmt' => $post->post_date_gmt
);
wp_update_post($post_information);
```